# One coil is always active on my stepper motor(ULN2003)

Tags: python

When I startup my pi or stop my script, the led on the ULN2003 lights up and stays. That means that one coil is active and the motor is heating up. At the end of my script I introduced a few lines of code which set all input pins to zero.

```py
stepper_pins = [3, 4, 18, 27]
for pin in range(4):
            GPIO.output(self.stepper_pins[pin], 0)
```

This code works, but when I exit the program the led lights up again.

Comment: You need to post ALL the code.  I can guess what might be happening but that guess might be wrong.

Comment: https://github.com/kaffarell/cuckoo_clock_raspberrypi

Comment: I dont think this has something to do with the code, because when I start the pi normally, the led is also on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't looked through all the code so this is still a guess.

If there is a call to cleanup() in the code during exit that will switch the GPIO you use back to INPUT mode.

You are using GPIO 3 and 4.  When set as INPUTS they will both be high.  GPIO 3 will be high because it has an external 1k8 pull-up to 3V3.  GPIO 4 will be high as it defaults to having a weak internal pull-up to 3V3.

I suggest you substitute other GPIOs for 3 and 4.  Any spare GPIO higher than number 7 should be fine.

Comment: https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjz5obm-6_jAhVDjqQKHbMmB4EQjRx6BAgBEAU&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.researchgate.net%2Ffigure%2FGPIO-From-Raspberry-Pi-3-B-model_fig3_312218161&psig=AOvVaw0pIXEvA0NrJggVa9i64bzK&ust=1563041027271745
So when I use the pins with the parentesis, I get for default a high output. Did I get this right?

Comment: No, GPIO 0-8 (not 7 as I thought) have internal pull-ups to 3V3 enabled at boot.  If they are set as INPUTS they will read high unless there is a stronger external voltage.  Additionally GPIO 2/3 have hard wired 1K8 pull-ups to 3V3.